# Unable to jump to function definition after opening C++ project in VSCode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I use VSCode to remotely open a project on Ubuntu through remote ssh on Windows.

My project consists of only three files: `a1.h`, `a1.cc`, and `main.cc`. When I first opened the project, I was unable to jump to the definition of the `print` function in a1.h by clicking F12.

However, if I opened `a1.cc` and tried again to jump to the definition of `print` in `a1.h`, it worked correctly.

a1.h

```
#ifndef A1_H
#define A1_H

class A1 {
public:
    void print();
};

#endif
```

a1.cc

```
#include "a1.h"
#include <iostream>

void A1::print()
{
    std::cout << "hello world";
}
```

main.cc

```
#include "a1.h"

int main() {
    A1 obj;
    obj.print();
}
```

I tried two ways, but they didn't work.

1.Configure `Files::associations` in VSCode settings
[image]

2.Configure `fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 524288`

Comment: Did you try restarting the IDE after making changes/installing any extensions?

Comment: Yes, I have tried to restart the IDE.

Comment: Since you are using Remote SSH, you may want to install necessary extensions for Remote SSH. Normally your extensions are installed on your local machine, so for Remote SSH you will have to install extensions for that machine as well.